# Good and simple book series for beginners like Oxford Bookworms series

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources, apprentissage

As an English learner, I found Oxford "Bookworms series" and "Dominoes" very useful to enhance my reading skill and my English vocabulary.

For example, about Bookworms series, each book in the series is graded based on the grammar and the count of the headwords the reader needs to know. So as an instance a learner would know that he/she can read books graded 'stage 4' or lower.

I am a beginner in French and wonder if there are good reading materials – like what mentioned above  in English – for learning French.

Comment: I don't know this kind of *book series*, ranked by level. But you may look for the books we give to child to learn french. Like [Monsieur Madame](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsieur_Madame) or [Ratus](http://www.ratus.com/romans_liste.php)

Comment: this is not as common as in English, but maybe this link could help http://www.europeanbookshop.com/series.php?xkey=LCFF&subject[]=FRE&section[]=m4&section[]=c21&age[]=6&offset=30&offset=60

Answer (score 3):

La série *[Easy Readers](http://www2.klett.de/sixcms/list.php?page=titelfamilie&titelfamilie=Easy%20Readers&modul=produktansicht&view=224532)* offre diverses lectures en français simplifié avec quatre niveaux: A, B, C et D.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

- *First French Reader for Beginners Bilingual for Speakers of English*, graded French readers tome 1 and tome 2, by Eugene Gotye
- *Aventures canadiennes* series by Ian Fraser
- *Petits Contes Sympathiques*, by June K. Phillips

Answer (score 1):

When I was a younger, French young person, I found the reading of books in the Zanzibar collection (by Milan editions) to be extremely well-written.

I believe that if you are starting to read in French (this is not clear in your question, and I am not familiar with your "Bookworms" / "Dominoes" examples you cite, but I assume you need entry-level French novels), these books would be well suited for you.

http://www.decitre.fr/collection/zanzibar/

Now if you are looking for books that explore stylistic figures that French writers often use, I recommend "Les Sorcières sont N.R.V." by Yak Rivais:

http://atelierdecriturepaca.over-blog.com/article-35317584.html